# 'Unbalanced quote exception' while running html file on Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I have a problem running any html file on `Netbeans 8.0`. It gives me following exception -

```
unbalanced quotes in -Xbootclasspath/p:
C:\Users\KEM'S PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PrisonWare\lib\javaee-endorsed-api-6.0\javax.annotation.jar;
C:\Users\KEM'S PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PrisonWare\lib\javaee-endorsed-api-6.0\jaxb-api-osgi.jar;
C:\Users\KEM'S PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PrisonWare\lib\javaee-endorsed-api-6.0\webservices-api-osgi.jar
```

I really don't understand this exception at all.

Comment: The first: It is not a good idea, to have quotes in a path. e.g. `C:\Users\KEM'S` : Set your `-Xbootclasspath/p` like : `"C:\Users\KEM'S PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PrisonWare\lib\javaee-endorsed-api-6.0\javax.annotation.jar";"..."` .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the quotes and the spaces in the path look like the culprit.